# A 90's Sci-Fi movie about a town repeatedly attacked by a monster and then forgetting

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

I believe it is either a mid-90's or possibly later, US 'Sci-Fi original movie'. I am fairly certain I watched it on the Sci-Fi channel, though I tried browsing through a list of old Syfy (Sci Fi at the time), original movies and could not find one that matched.

The plot is something along the lines of a young man (in his late teens / early 20s) along with his girlfriend, and I think he had a dog, go to visit his grandfather. While their visit, some mysterious deaths occur. I think it started off with a few teenagers going missing but not drawing too much concern from the local Sheriff.

The grandfather eventually reveals to his grandson that he knows it is actually a monster attacking the town, and the rest of the town regards him as crazy. The grandson eventually sees the monster and believes his grandfather so they set out to kill it, but the grandfather explains how the monster keeps coming back every year (or possibly multiple years at random intervals) and he has to find a new way to kill it each time (due to the monster somehow becoming impervious to that type of death meaning you could not shoot it in the head twice).

I think the grandfather gets injured and so the grandson has to take up the task of killing the monster alone, which he eventually does through some plan (though I do not remember any of those details), and the twist at the end of the movie is after explaining to his grandfather how he killed it, his grandfather exclaims that he has already killed the monster that same way in the past, implying heavily the monster is still currently alive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Monster!"(1999 TV movie)

Here is a plot synopsis from one of the critic reviews on IMDb.

"A small town is stuck in a curse in which every three years, the monster from the fictitious monster films made in their town, comes to life to try and destroy the town. The star of those old films, Lloyd, is the only one who knows this curse and has been stopping the monster for years. The townspeople don’t know this and think that he’s crazy. But every time he beats it, it comes back even stronger and harder to beat. So he enlists the help of his grandson to stop it this time."

It has all the plot points you mention and it was a Tv movie. You can watch the full movie from Youtube below.